# rails 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

i'm trying to fetch data from database in rails, this is my controller file

```
 class PathsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  def getall
    @result = Path.select('x', 'y')
  end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @result }
    end

end
```

Here is my js function

```
function makelines()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",// => method type
    url: "/path", // => Target function that will be return result 
    contentType:"application/json",
    success: function(result){
      result = JSON.parse(result);
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Here is the route

```
  match '/path => 'Paths#getall', via: [:get, :post], :default => { :format => 'json' }
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about error?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do in this circumstance is consult your console or logs; that will be the most helpful in pinpointing the exception.

That said, I'll take a guess and warrant that the issue is that you are invoking a `respond_to` outside of a controller action

```
def getall
    @result = Path.select('x', 'y')
end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @result }
  end
```

Should be:

```
def getall
    @result = Path.select('x', 'y')

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @result }
    end
end
```

Comment: log:
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template paths/getall, application/getall with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :web_console_v2], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/Users/Ali Ammar/police/police/app/views"
  * "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views"
):

Comment: This is an issue with `respond_to`, since it's not defined within your action, rails will default to looking for a template to render the response.

Comment: so how to fix it  ?

Comment: Did you try the code I suggest in my answer? Move your respond to within the get method

Comment: Recommendation: read this blog post on `respond_to` format, https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/respond-to-without-all-the-pain/ His blog contains a lot of interesting Ruby and Rails related articles.

Answer (score 0):

Let's improve your code a little bit:

```
def getall
    @results = Path.select('x', 'y')
    respond_to do |format|
      if @results.count > 0
        format.json { render json: @results, , status: :ok }
      else
        format.json { render json: @results.errors, , status: :not_found }
      end
    end
end
```

Per Rails conventions it would be better to return `results` instead of `result` as you are returning more than 1 item.

I also think that as you are returning a JSON object to your AJAX method it would be good to return either a 200 (:ok) or a 404 (:not_found, in the event no record is in the database)

Comment: Returning a 404 for an empty collection seems odd to me. This makes sense for an individual item `GET /paths/1` but it's perfectly valid and cleaner (IMHO) to have an empty result set. Thinking about this a a page load, you wouldn't 404 a user visiting a "paths/all" page, you'd just tell them that there are currently no paths (and would they care to add one?).

Comment: You can also opt for a 200 with a null payload. But do not be confused that responses from the server will have to be managed by your JS code. So handling of the errors still has to be propagated to the UI. If you have a 404 you just have to catch this error and display the right information to the user, such as create a new record.

Comment: JSON status code (google) https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes They would use a 404 in that case